# Vertically expand div to border of other div - both absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css, position, absolute, expand

I have two absolutely positioned divs, one fixed at the top-left corner and the other fixed at the bottom-left corner. They both have text inside them. The height of div.top expands to fit its content (which can vary). Instead, the height of div.bottom should expand up to the bottom of div.top.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7m5P/2/)

```
 body { 100%; margin:0 }

 .top { / * div expands to fit-content */
     position: absolute;
     top:0; left:0;
     height: auto; 
     width: 30%;
     border: 1px solid;
 }

 .bottom { /* div.bottom top should match div.top bottom */
     position: absolute;
     bottom:0;left:0;
     width: 30%;
     border: 1px solid;
 }
```

Comment: with pure CSS and the top `div`'s `height` set to `auto` ... thats gonna be tough.

Comment: You can have something like http://jsfiddle.net/U7m5P/3/ but you are just covering up the content of 2. Also remove `/ * div expands to fit-content */` or correct it to `/* div expands to fit-content */`. I think you need js to do it if you don't want to cover up the bottom one

Comment: Looks like doing it just with CSS is going to be hard. How would I do it with JS?